# Do any CSS media queries work for Kindle ios app?

Tags: kindle, kindle-app, media-queries, ios

In section 8.1.4 of the Kindle Formatting Guide, it provides an example of a css media query to target ipad devices. It looks like this:

```
@media (device-width: 768px) {}
```

But the example is unclear; is this a simple media query used when you upload epubs into the ibooks app? Or is this an actual query which is digested and followed  by the Kindle app on the ipad?

Are there any media queries which will be seen by Kindle for ios?

**UPDATE:** I've been investigating and testing some more. It seems that the heart of my question is how the Kindle app for ios handles collisions between "@media" and "@amzn-kf8" media queries. The Kindle documentation doesn't address this accurately. I'll post my findings soon.

Comment: What did you end up concluding on this? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or is this an actual query which is digested and followed by the Kindle app on the ipad?

This is an actual media query that you can use in Kindle KF8 books. 
For example, you could use the following code to display paragraphs in red if the orientation is changed to landscape.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/
  @media (orientation: landscape) {
  p {
    color: red;
  }
  }
  /*]]>*/
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Media query test</h1>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ac tellus nunc.
  Phasellus imperdiet leo metus, et gravida lacus. Donec metus ligula, elementum at
  pellentesque pellentesque, suscipit ac nunc. Etiam lobortis, massa ac aliquam auctor,
  augue nisl sagittis urna, at dapibus tellus erat ullamcorper ligula.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that media queries only work with AZK (KF8) files. (Kindle Previewer will automatically generate an .azk file if you set the default device mode to Kindle for iPad/iPhone.)

Comment: (Thanks for your comment. I'm currently in the middle of testing various media queries). I think my issue is with collisions between "@media" and "@amzn" . I'll report back with my results.

Comment: I just wanted to say that kindle files support all kinds of media queries, including both proprietary and generic. Generally they don't work on e-ink, and work fairly well on other devices.

Comment: @Nemo Curious, what's with the `CDATA` in comments?  Is that to handle some reading system bug?